# Buildkite use shell variables in global hook

Tags: docker, shell, buildkite

I used a variable in my pipeline script like this.

```sh
# This shell is a pipeline shell script

export container_id=`docker run -d MY_CONTAINER`
```

then regardless of the success of the result, I want to remove my container using `container_id`, like this.

```sh
# This shell is a global exit hook

docker rm ${docker stop $container_id}
```

but it does not work. What can I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [command
substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/command-substitution.html):

```
docker rm $(docker stop $container_id)
```